# Javascript load asynchronous with dependencies

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, dependencies

i try to load different .js and .html files only when needed and asynchronous. But now i have the problem, that some files need other files to be loaded before.
I tried to solve this problem with the dependencies variable. later i check every 50ms if the dependencies are loaded, if not, they have to be loaded before every other needed file.

Here is my code.

```
var dependencies = {
    Module1: [],
    Module2: ["Module1"],
    loadStates: {
        Module1: false,
        Module2: false
    }
};
function initModule(id, moduleID, module) {
    var moduleInitialData = br6_config.moduleInitialData[id];
    if (moduleInitialData) {
        function loadModule(target, name) {
            var isLoaded = true;
            if (isLoaded === false) {
                console.log("file already loaded");
            }
            $(target).load("html/modules/" + name + ".html", function (response, status, xhr) {
                console.log(name + ".html" + " " + status);

                var modulesToLoad = dependencies[name];
                for (var i = 0; i < modulesToLoad.length; i++) {
                    var moduleToLoad = modulesToLoad[i];
                    var interval = setInterval(function () {
                        if (dependencies.loadStates[moduleToLoad] === false) {
                            loadJS(moduleToLoad);
                            clearInterval(interval);
                            if (dependencies.loadStates[name] === false) {
                                loadJS(name);
                            }
                        }
                    }, 50);
                }
                function loadJS(name) {
                    $.getScript("js/modules/" + name + ".js").done(function (textStatus) {
                        console.log(name + ".js geladen");
                        isLoaded = true;

                        if (name === Module1) {
                            module.instance = new Module1(id, moduleInitialData);
                            dependencies.loadStates[name] = true;
                        }
                        if (name === Module2) {
                            module.instance = new Module2(id, moduleInitialData);
                            dependencies.loadStates[name] = true;
                        }
                    }).fail(function (error, b, c) {
                        console.log(name + ".js nicht geladen");
                        console.log(error);
                        console.log(b);
                        console.log(c);
                    });
                }
            });
        }
        if (moduleID === "module1") {
            loadModule('#module1, Module1);
        }
        if (moduleID === "module2") {
            loadModule('#module2, Module2);
        }
```

Sometimes everything works, but sometimes my code wants to load Module2 before Module1 and thus i get an error. So there is some problem with checking the dependencies.

Can anyone help me out with this? I would really appreciate some help!

Comment: why not using a dependency manager like require.JS (or better, do it using webpack)

Comment: the code you posted has simple syntax errors, if this is the code you are actually using, it could not work

Comment: Create one script that provides a function to register (core) and add scripts as modules. A module can be loaded by calling the core with it's src. A module can call for other modules the same way. The dependencies are managed in the module itself. Be sure to check if a module is loading at the moment / is already loaded when calling.